# How to process payments (credit cards, PayPal) in Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, paypal

I want users to be able to buy tickets via Windows Phone application and do not want to use web browser for these purposes. The ticket price may be different.

Is it possible to *process payments* via Wallet app or integration with certain processing systems is required?

Also please suggest the best practices for purchasing process within Windows Phone app.

Comment: look => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx You can create  consomable product for buy many times or Durable product just one time like remove ads.

Comment: The ticket price may be different every time. So it's impossible to create an IAP product for each ticket or set of tickets.

Comment: SDK paypal exist for windows phone 8 => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Comment: Or a github project for windows 8 https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that accurate but, you can use a paypal address creator and a webbrowser component.

try to do this (needs another server :( - try a free one )

http://webdesign.about.com/od/ecommerce/a/create-a-paypal-shopping-cart.htm